# A lambda's closures can be mangled when another calling lambda uses default capture?

Tags: c++

This seems like a compiler bug, but it occurs in both gcc and clang (and maybe others).

If a function takes a lambda `f` and it creates a thread from another lambda `g` which calls `f`, `f` can quietly lose access to its captured variables. Here's a demonstration.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::thread;

template<typename F>
__attribute__((noinline)) // inlining hides the bug
thread* callMeLater1(F f)
{
  return new thread(
    [&]() {
      // ...
      // Insert sleep logic.
      // ...

      f();
    });
}

template<typename F>
__attribute__((noinline))
thread* callMeLater2(F f)
{
  return new thread(
    [f]() {
      // ...
      // Insert sleep logic.
      // ...

      f();
    });
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int a = 42;

  cout << "orign: " << ((void*) &a) << endl;

  auto f = [&]() {
             cout << "later: " << ((void*) &a) << endl;
           };

  thread* t1 = callMeLater1(f);
  t1->join();
  delete t1;

  thread* t2 = callMeLater2(f);
  t2->join();
  delete t2;

  return 0;
}
```

Here are the results.

```
orign: 0x7ffee88727ac
later: 0
later: 0x7ffee88727ac
```

The call to `f` inside `callMeLater1` is corrupted. `f`'s accesses to `a` will be broken, causing silent bugs or segfaults. When `f` is called inside `callMeLater2`, which doesn't use default capture `&`, the function works correctly.

Is this expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undefined behavior.

The lambda captures, by reference, the parameter to `callMeLater1`. This parameter gets destroyed, of course, as soon as `callMeLater1` returns.

Nothing guarantees you that the new execution thread invokes the passed-in closure before `callmeLater1` returns. As such, the passed-in callable object can get destroyed before the new thread attempts to invoke it, resulting in undefined behavior.